# The scheduler seems to be running under uWSGI, but threads have disabled.You must run uWSGI with the --enable-threads option for the scheduler to work

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, deployment, pythonanywhere

I'm deploying django app to pythonanywhere where i used APScheduler for automatically send expire mail whenever subscription end date exceed.

I don't know how to enable threads, so that my web app runs perfectly on pythonanywhere.

Answer (score 0):

On hosting platforms like PythonAnywhere, there might be multiple copies of your site running at different times, in order to serve the traffic that you get.  So you should not use an in-process scheduler to perform periodic tasks; instead, you should use the platform's built-in scheduled tasks function.